# How can use ajax in asp.net mvc core?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have used jquery ajax twice in a single view.
The first works fine, but the second sends the zero value as the input parameter to the corresponding action,I don't know why?

```
<tr>
     <th>(@((int)ViewBag.BoonCount))</th>
         <td class="text-right">
             <input onchange="SetBoon()" class="form-control" type="number" name="Boon" id="MBoon" min="0" max="@((int)ViewBag.BoonCount)" value="" />
              <script>
               function SetBoon() {
                    var BoonVal = $('#MBoon').val();

                     $.ajax({
                            url: '/Users/SetBoon',
                            method: 'post',
                            contentType: 'json',
                            data: { fID: '@Factor.ID', BValue: BoonVal }
                          });

                    }
             </script>
          </td>
```

and it is my action code:

```
public string SetBoon(int fID, int BValue){}
```

The action receives zero as the input parameter.I even tested the @Factor.ID  before entering the SetBoon function and had a valid value.

Comment: try it with removing the contenttype in $.ajax

Comment: you're sending factorID as a string and not an int. Remove the single quotes, i.e. `data: { fID: @Factor.ID, BValue: BoonVal }`

Comment: @ADyson I did your point, but still returns zero

Comment: Well, what is the value of `Factor.ID` when the page is first rendered? What value are you expecting? You should be able to see from your rendered page source what it's passing. Does BValue get populated correctly?

Comment: @ADyson This is the integer type and should send 31

Comment: ok, and what _does_ it send? I don't mean what is _received_ by the API, I mean what is _sent_ by the browser? Again, look at your page source. the value of Factor.ID should be rendered statically into the source when the view is created. Then, when the ajax call runs, look at the network tab, examine the request body and see if it passes 31 or not.  Check BValue is sending correctly as well. Also, as I just asked, does BValue get populated correctly when the API receives it? Are both fields causing a problem, or just fID? This is all basic debugging that you should be doing routinely.

Comment: In the network section is sent 31 ,BValue does not send anything

Comment: If you find the variables are being sent with the values you expect, I would try removing `contentType: "json"` from the ajax options. I don't think it's necessary, it should be able to accept normal urlencoded values, this is the default and is usually less hassle. You can still specify your "data" option as a JS/JSON object, and jQuery will encode it for you automatically.

Comment: for BValue, it obviously depends what you typed in your MBoon field, so check that you completed it correctly. You can always do `alert(BoonVal);` just before the $.ajax command, to double check it.

Comment: Thanks guy it fixed.

Comment: That's good. Out of interest, what was the full solution in the end? You can post an answer to your own question, btw, for future readers' interest.

Answer (score 1):

I must replace contentType by dataType in the ajax,if I remove contentType in the amount returned from the action to the view I encountered with another error.

Answer (score 0):

json is not a contentType. It is a dataType for the response. If you want to specify the request data type, use

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```